# How to get value from a Dynamic Form Item

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I have a form where I can create new inputs fields. ***check out***: [CodeSandBox of My Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lifmv)

How I can capture the value of each created input dynamically using formControl?

Here is my code:

**My html**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-form-dynamic-form-item',
  template: `
    <form nz-form [formGroup]="validateForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <nz-form-item *ngFor="let control of listOfControl; let i = index">
        <nz-form-label [nzXs]="24" [nzSm]="4" *ngIf="i === 0" [nzFor]="control.controlInstance">
          Passengers
        </nz-form-label>
        <nz-form-control
          [nzXs]="24"
          [nzSm]="20"
          [nzOffset]="i === 0 ? 0 : 4"
          nzErrorTip="Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
        >
          <input
            class="passenger-input"
            nz-input
            placeholder="placeholder"
            [attr.id]="control.id"
            [formControlName]="control.controlInstance"
          />
          <i nz-icon nzType="minus-circle-o" class="dynamic-delete-button" (click)="removeField(control, $event)"></i>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-control [nzXs]="{ span: 24, offset: 0 }" [nzSm]="{ span: 20, offset: 4 }">
          <button nz-button nzType="dashed" class="add-button" (click)="addField($event)">
            <i nz-icon nzType="plus"></i>
            Add field
          </button>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-control [nzXs]="{ span: 24, offset: 0 }" [nzSm]="{ span: 20, offset: 4 }">
          <button nz-button nzType="primary">Submit</button>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
    </form>
```

**My TS**

```
export class NzDemoFormDynamicFormItemComponent implements OnInit {
  validateForm!: FormGroup;
  listOfControl: Array<{ id: number; controlInstance: string }> = [];

  addField(e?: MouseEvent): void {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    const id = this.listOfControl.length > 0 ? this.listOfControl[this.listOfControl.length - 1].id + 1 : 0;

    const control = {
      id,
      controlInstance: `passenger${id}`
    };
    const index = this.listOfControl.push(control);
    console.log(this.listOfControl[this.listOfControl.length - 1]);
    this.validateForm.addControl(
      this.listOfControl[index - 1].controlInstance,
      new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    );
  }

  removeField(i: { id: number; controlInstance: string }, e: MouseEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.listOfControl.length > 1) {
      const index = this.listOfControl.indexOf(i);
      this.listOfControl.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.listOfControl);
      this.validateForm.removeControl(i.controlInstance);
    }
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    for (const i in this.validateForm.controls) {
      if (this.validateForm.controls.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        this.validateForm.controls[i].markAsDirty();
        this.validateForm.controls[i].updateValueAndValidity();
      }
    }
    console.log(this.validateForm.value);
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.validateForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.addField();
  }
}
```

Its possible using formControl to get values of the  created input components?

Lets Say i have 2 input created:

input1: text01 <-- value
input2: text02 <-- value

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve.

To get the value of yours FormControls, you already used `this.validateForm.value`. Isn't that enought ?

Btw, `FormArray` is a better choice here instead of `FormGroup`. It will simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form #sampleForm="ngForm" ...otherparams>
   <fieldset *ngFor=".....">
    <div ngModelGroup="groupnamehere">
     //input and label with name and for
    </div>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

In the .ts file

`@ViewChild('sampleForm', null) form: NgForm`

And then use this value to process the data as needed.

This will create an object for you with the ngModelGroup name as the object key when you hit submit.